# Prevent android to start another instance of app

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm unable to make my app to run only one instance. When I press on the app to start it then press the home button and press on the app start another instance the previous instance is not being killed before starting a new one. When the app is loaded I press back button to close it and then another instance pops up right after closing the first one...

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".StartUpActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**StartUpActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent activityIntent;
            // DO STUFF
            activityIntent = new Intent(context, RegNewUser.class);
            startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: "Prevent android to start another instance of app" -- there will only ever be one instance of your *app*. There may be more than one instance of an *activity*. An activity is not an app.

Answer (score 3):

Do not create a new thread to start a new activity. This code must be executed in the UI thread.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);


    Intent activityIntent;
    activityIntent = new Intent(context, RegNewUser.class);
    startActivity(activityIntent);

}
```

Comment: is it ok if i start a new activity inside `OnPostExecute` of AsyncTask?

Comment: it is clearly much better. However, I suggest to create a "communication channel" between your thread and the UI thread. You can for instance use an Handler https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html